# Python remove duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates, buffer

I have written this to remove duplicates from lines of a file and to write the lines without duplicates to another file. I am getting though the error: 
"TypeError: expected a character buffer object"
What can I do to avoid this?

```
f2 = open('withoutduplicates.txt', 'w')
f1 = open('elements.txt')
lines = f1.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    L=[line]
    newlist=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(L) if ii not in L[:n]]
    f2.write(newlist)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

File `f1` (elements.txt) looks like:

```
88208   89630   88744   89078   89659   89886   89886   89886   89886   354847  354844  356602  358593  89886   89886   89886   89886   358594  354848  356605  358675
88209   89633   89866   89646   90021   88661   88661   88661   88661   358601  358639  358641  358603  88661   88661   88661   88661   354386  354388  354387  354389
88210   89467   88530   89143   89146   89355   89355   89355   89355   353523  353519  356900  356915  89355   89355   89355   89355   357778  353521  356902  356914
88211   88842   88506   89364   88767   89784   89784   89784   89784   353343  353345  355014  355012  89784   89784   89784   89784   355412  353346  357806  355018
88212   1169    1167    88469   89586   89271   89271   89271   89271   97466   350978  353064  350985  89271   89271   89271   89271   350984  350979  353063  357449
88213   89720   88909   89665   89129   89411   89411   89411   89411   355781  355780  356837  356838  89411   89411   89411   89411   357967  355779  357965  356836
```

Comment: Both enumerates seem superfluous as well as L=[line]. Is that really all code?

Comment: you can try creating a set to remove the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a list, I have two scenario depending on the nature of your outputs.

1- If you wanna have an output like this: 
['88208   89630   88744   89078   89659   89886   89886   89886   89886   354847  354844  356602  358593  89886   89886   89886   89886   358594  354848  356605  358675'] 
........... 
........... 
then change this --> `f2.write('{}\n'.format(str(newlist)))`

2. Output like this: 
   88208   89630   88744   89078   89659   89886   89886   89886   89886   354847  354844  356602  358593  89886   89886   89886   89886   358594  354848  356605  358675 
   .......
   .......

then change this --> `f2.write('{}\n'.format(newlist[0]))`

Comment: Forgot, you need to: L=[line.strip()]

Answer (score 0):

This code works and remove the duplicate:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f1:
    with open('withoutduplicates.txt', 'w') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            L = line.strip().split(' ')
            new_line = set([l.strip() for l in L if l])
            f2.write('{}\n'.format('  '.join(new_line)))
```

Comment: are you sure? I have tested it and it is not working. I am trying a solution with seen or unique but I cannot make it.

Comment: It worked on my side with the same input you've listed above

Comment: Is this your output, what you are showing in two different formats? If yes, then you will see that duplicates are still there

Comment: You can ignore my first answer that was about only solving the issue you've had "TypeError: expected a character buffer object", but not remove the duplicate

Comment: But in my second answer, the code will remove all the duplicates

Comment: I am speaking about your 2nd answer. I have tried it and the duplicates remained.

Comment: Could you explain a bit again when you said duplicate. Is it duplicate in each line or duplicate in entire file content ?

Comment: Duplicates of each line. Not duplicate lines in entire file.